# cant find classes code while reverse engineering xamarin apk

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, apk, reverse-engineering

I Wrote a simple root detection app using Xamarin framework in visual studio 2019.
now i want to reverse engineer the output apk for academic purposes to bypass the root detection mechanism. for that purpose, I converted classes.dex file to jar and used jd-gui to read the code. but I cannot find the code i have written for root detection anywhere in the files. is there any other thing I should have done to achieve that purpose?! what am I missing?!
here is the mainactivity.cs code :

```
    using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Widget;

namespace RootDetection
{
    [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
            Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
            bool root = RootCheck.IsRoot();
            button.Click += delegate
            {
                if (root)
                    Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "The Device is Rooted!", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                else
                    Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "The Device is not Rooted.", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            };
        }
        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the RootCheck class code :

```
    using System;
using Java.Lang;
using Process = Java.Lang.Process;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace RootDetection
{
    public static class RootCheck
    {
        public static bool IsRoot()
        {
            bool retval = false;
            Process suProcess;
            try
            {
                suProcess = Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec("su");
                var os = new Java.IO.BufferedWriter(new Java.IO.OutputStreamWriter(suProcess.OutputStream));
                var osRes = new Java.IO.BufferedReader(new Java.IO.InputStreamReader(suProcess.InputStream));
                if (null != os && null != osRes)
                {
                    os.Write("id\n");
                    os.Flush();
                    string currUid = osRes.ReadLine();
                    bool exitSu = false;
                    if (null == currUid)
                    {
                        retval = false;
                        exitSu = false;
                        Console.WriteLine("Can't get root access or denied by user");
                    }
                    else if (true == currUid.Contains("uid=0"))
                    {
                        retval = true;
                        exitSu = true;
                        Console.WriteLine("Root access granted");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        retval = false;
                        exitSu = true;
                        Console.WriteLine("Root access rejected: " + currUid);
                    }

                    if (exitSu)
                    {
                        os.Write("exit\n");
                        os.Flush();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Java.Lang.Exception e)
            {
                retval = false;
                Console.WriteLine("Root access rejected [" + e.Class.Name + "] : " + e.Message);
            }

            return retval;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you include some code samples that show what you're trying to do? I see that you've explained your issue, so backing it up with samples of what you've tried, and issues you have encountered, will help people answer your question better here.

Comment: Xamarin is not a .Net to Java trans-compiler, so the .Net classes are contained in CIL-based assemblies and/or native SO libraries, not Dalvik files. So you would need to either extract the CIL assemblies and convert them to .Net code OR if the Xamarin.Android app is AOT'd then you would need to extract the Android native shared libraries that Xamarin created and convert those to from machine code->assembly code->.Net code (via tools like  Ghidra/JDA/...)

Comment: @Christine thanks a lot for your answer. I included the code in the question.

Comment: @SushiHangover i tried to read the dll files using jetbrains dotpeek, i checked projectname.dll file in assemblies folder of the apk. still no luck.

Comment: @MuhammadRn `..still no luck...` That does not explain what type of problem you are having...

Comment: did you find any solution ?